# Gronwall inequality for a $2$-dimensional system of linear differential inequalities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $$z(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t)\end{pmatrix}~,~ A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -\beta \\ \alpha & -(\alpha + \beta)\end{pmatrix}$$ satisfies the following system of linear differential inequalities $$z'(t) \leq A\,z(t)$$ where $\alpha, \beta > 0$ are fixed constants, and $x(t), y(t) \in  [0,\infty)$, I am wondering if there is a vectorized version of Gronwall lemma which allows me to deduce that  $$z(t)\leq \mathrm{e}^{At}\,z(0).$$ It seems hard to find a literature which addresses precisely my question. Any help (including referring to precise literatures) will be greatly appreciated!

---

Side note: by writing $u \leq v$ for $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2_+$ I mean that each component of $u$ is less than or equal to the corresponding component of $v$. Also (and unfortunately), the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are not all non-negative, which means that the discussion mentioned in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239751/differential-inequalities-for-a-strictly-diagonal-dominant-system-of-linear-odes) may not be applicable...

Comment: You have some type of DE there right? $z' = Az$ perhaps ?

Comment: I believe some years ago I have seen abstract Gronwall inequalities for a topological space which has a partial order and if the fixed point operator respects the partial order, then you get the same conclusion

Comment: @dezdichado Hello, thank you for your comment. I am actually not interested in "abstract results" applied to general (topological) space and I only care about the validity of such "2-dimensional" Gronwall inequality...

Comment: my point was that if such a theorem exists, it will likely be a general result since the usual generalizations from ODE to PDE always involves the Euclidean norm $\|x\|_p$ and the usual $\leq$ relation in $\mathbb{R}.$ Your Pareto like relation is probably not tractable from the typical methods.

Comment: May I know what you mean by "Pareto like relation"

Comment: In the context of optimization, a vector $x$ Pareto dominates $y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ for each components and sometimes we write $y\preceq x$ and it's a partial order on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ It's the same component-wise ordering you want and it's inherently different than the usual bounds we see in PDE in terms of some norm of a vector.

Comment: Here is a statement of Gronwall's in a general Banach space that you may be able to manipulate to your needs: https://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/gronwall.pdf

Comment: Thank you @whpowell96

Comment: @whpowell96  But this notes only treats equality relation (i.e., differential equations rather than differential inequalities).

Comment: The theorem in this  article states Gronwall for a normwise differential inequality,  but not componentwise

Answer (score 2):

Such an inequality cannot be expected.

Firstly, the statement is equivalent to saying that for any function $f:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^2$  that satisfies $f(t) \le 0$ for all $t$ the conclusion holds
$$
z'(t) = Az(t) + f(t), \; z(0) = 0 \; \Longrightarrow \, z(t) \le 0 \; \forall t 
$$

Consider now the case where
$f(t) =  - (\gamma, \delta)^T$
with positive constants $\gamma, \delta$.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
x'(t) &= - \beta y(t) - \gamma \\
y'(t) &= \alpha x(t) - (\alpha + \beta) y(t) - \delta \\ 
x''(t) &= - \beta y'(t) = - \beta(\alpha x(t) - (\alpha + \beta) y(t) - \delta) \\
&= - \alpha \beta x(t) - (\alpha + \beta)x'(t) + \beta \delta - (\alpha + \beta) \gamma
\end{align}
$$
The general solution of this equation is
$$
x(t) = C_1 e^{-\alpha t} + C_2 e^{-\beta t} + \frac{\beta \delta - (\alpha + \beta) \gamma}{\alpha \beta}
$$
Obviousy if $\beta \delta > (\alpha + \beta) \gamma$, the solution will eventually become positive.

Your desired inequality is a special case of the implication
$$
u' - Au \le v' - Av \, \forall \, t > 0, \; u(0) \le v(0) \; \Longrightarrow \; u \le v \, \forall t \ge 0
$$
which is correct if all off-diagonal entries of $A$ are non-negative.

Comment: Hello Professor, thank you for your answer. May I know if you can elaborate more on your second sentence: "First of all,  the statement is equivalent to saying that for any function ...". I do not quite understanding why my statement is equivalent to your first statement **for any $f$**

Comment: Given $f(t)$ with $f(t) \le 0 \, \forall t$, you can solve $z' = Az + f$. Then $z' \le  Az$, Your question is whether in that case $z(t) \le w(t)$ for all $t$, where $w' = Aw$ and $z(0) = w(0)$. Conversely, assume you know $z' \le Az$. Now set $f(t) = z'(t) - Az(t)$. Then $f(t) \le 0\,  \forall t$ and $z' = Az + f$. Essentially  the differential inequality is equivalent to an inhomogeneous differential equation with a right hand side $f$ that satisfies a sign condition.